# Ubuntu freezes randomly when (un)plugging external monitor

Tags: crash, external-monitor

I have a Lenovo notebook with an Intel Core i5-4200U CPU and an Intel HD Graphics 4400 GPU.

When an external monitor is plugged or unplugged, sometimes the system crashes. But it seems random for me. Sometimes it works, sometimes it crashes. I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and run `sudo service lightdm restart` which will kill my current session and I can re-log in.

I've read that kernel updates will help, but this seems not to help me, since I have the 4.10 kernel installed. I know it's not the latest one, but I've read that from 4.4 the error is fixed.

```
$ uname -r
4.10.0-28-generic
```

I'm grateful for every hint, thank you ! :)